# realgud ipdb how to highlight line being debugged

Tags: ipython

I debug a python source file with

`M-x realgud:ipdb`
then call ipdb as  `python3 -m pdb <sourcepath> <args>`

I get 2 windows: ipdb ... shell    and  my source buffer.

How can I get the line being debugged to be highlighted?

Comment: I also get this

WARNING: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you write that don't line up.

```
python3 -m pdb <sourcepath> <args>
```

invokes `pdb`, not `ipdb`.  realgud looks for a prompt, and the one for ipdb is `ipdb>`. The prompt for `pdb` is `(Pdb)` and will not trigger look for postiion informatation when the wrong kind of prompt is printed.

Finally, I should say that if your are using Python and realgud [`trepan3k`](https://pypi.python.org/project/trepan3k) interacts with realgud much better.